# How to bind arrow keys in C?

Tags: c, key-bindings, arrow-keys

I am a beginner C coder and I want to know how the make it so the program will do this.

```
printf("which direction would you like to go?\n");
/*they type an arrow key*/
printf ("you went left/right/up/down\n");
```

I have a Mac

Comment: have you cheched anything on the net? must be loads of information on simple input handling available

Comment: The arrow keys can return a sequence of characters, and you have to parse that sequence. Also, the sequence may differ between platforms. It's probably easier to use a library such as [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for this, and there are variants of that library for Windows too.

Comment: Ncurses works like a charm on the Mac. Plenty of good documentation to be found on google as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try these suggestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-c-c-166055/). You can get the ASCII codes by
     getch()

Answer (score 0):

Pure C (and C++ by that matter) doesn't even require your system to have a keyboard, a mouse, or a screen (from the C++ FAQ, at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html).

I would recommend searching for some sort of GUI (like Qt or GTK) in order to do stuff like that. I believe it is possible for ncurses to bind those sorts of events, if a command-line interface is what you want to do.